# Router connected hard drive not showing files copied over from from a Mac

Tags: windows, hard-drive, router, mac

I have recently connected a Seagate 4TB Expansion Desktop Hard Drive to my router (Sagemcom FAST4353-A from Belong ISP) to use as a shared drive for my Windows 10 PC and a Mac via USB. I am able to access the drive from both the PC and Mac, but found after uploading a bunch of files from the Mac that a lot of them are not showing in the file explorers on either my PC or Mac.

When I plug the hard drive directly into either my PC or Mac the files all show up but when I plug it back into the router, the files are missing again. When plugging into the PC it says there is an error on the disk, but when scanning it says there are 0 errors.

I'm assuming this is something to do with the router but any suggestions on how to get this working would be fantastic.

Comment: I wonder if this is a limitation of the filesystem the drive is formatted with and the routers ability to reqd it?

Comment: I agree with the path @davidgo is talking about.  Please show us the filesystem you are using.